# wsdl2dispatch raises exception while generating server file

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, webserver, zsi

I want to implement a SOAP web server using python ZSI library. I tried solution described [here](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/cookbook.pdf), but I get exception while using `wsdl2dispatch` command as described in page 6 of the book:

```
wsdl2dispatch --extended mywsdl.xml
```

It raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/wsdl2dispatch", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ZSI==2.0rc3', 'console_scripts', 'wsdl2dispatch')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2649, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2303, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2313, in resolve
    raise ImportError(str(exc))
ImportError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wsdl2dispatch'
```

I have added `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` to the system `PATH`; still no change. Any idea how should I fix this?

*Note:* There is a workaround described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796440/are-there-any-working-examples-of-zolera-soap-infrastructure-zsi?answertab=active#tab-top) which was really useful; but it didn't use `wsdl2dispatch` command.

Comment: What is the version of your wsdl?

Comment: @Elektroi what do you mean? How should I get that?

Comment: The Wsdl file has a version, it was at the start of the wsdl file. The latest soap version is 1.2 and in ZSI documentations put that ZSI is for 1.1 soap version

Comment: @Elektroi if you mean XML version, it is `1.0`; there is no other version in my WSDL file; besides I think there is a problem in the lib, because when I call `wsdl2dispatch` with no argument, it returns the same exception.

Comment: Look at [https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12/](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12/)

Comment: @Elektroi, well according to `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"` in my WSDL file and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736845/can-a-wsdl-indicate-the-soap-version-1-1-or-1-2-of-the-web-service?answertab=active#tab-top), I use SOAP version 1.1.